# Using style.display triggered by date

Tags: javascript, css, function, if-statement, math

Brand new here so apologies for any breaks of protocol. Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

I have divs called "1st" "2nd" "3rd" etc and I'm trying to create an advent calendar format where the content of each day's div is only visible when the date arrives.

Below test case using dates 6th-8th but the divs remain always visible.

Quite new to JS so any help appreciated!

```
    <script type = "text/javascript">

    function myFunction() {

    var num = new Date().getDate(); //today's date as number

    if ((num <= 6)) {
        document.getElementById('6th').style.display = "none";
    }
    if ((num <= 7)) {
        document.getElementById('7th').style.display = "none";
    }
    if ((num <= 8)) {
        document.getElementById('8th').style.display = "none";
    }

    }

</script>

<div id="6th">
    6th
        </div>

<div id="7th">
    7th
        </div>

<div id="8th">
    8th
        </div>
```

Comment: This is a function. Where exactly in your code do you call it?

Comment: Insert the whole code snippet please, for it become clear, what's wrong.

Comment: I pasted your code and it works absolutely fine. Are you invoking the function anywhere? try adding `myFunction();`  above your closing `</script>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script type = "text/javascript">

    function myFunction() {

    var num = new Date().getDate(); //today's date as number

    if ((num <= 6)) {
        document.getElementById('6th').style.display = "none";
    }
    if ((num <= 7)) {
        document.getElementById('7th').style.display = "none";
    }
    if ((num <= 8)) {
        document.getElementById('8th').style.display = "none";
    }

    }

</script>

<div id="6th">
    6th
        </div>

<div id="7th">
    7th
        </div>

<div id="8th">
    8th
        </div>

<div id="9th">
    9th
        </div>
<script>myFunction()</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you are using to set display to none should work fine. 
Fist, make sure that the function you wrote called myFunction is actually being called. Simply add myFunction() before you close your script tag. Second, I believe you probably want < instead of <=. Also you can add console.log statements inside each of your if statements so that you can see if your code is reaching that point.